# PHP regex not new line

Tags: php, regex, newline

How do I have a regex statement that accepts any character except new lines. This includes anything but also includes new lines which is not what i want:

```
"/(.*)/"
```

Comment: You're wrong. See jeremy Ruten's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dot `.` does not match newlines unless you use the `s` modifier.

```
>>> preg_match("/./", "\n")
0
>>> preg_match("/./s", "\n")
1
```

Answer (score 4):

As written on the PHP Documentation page on Preg Modifiers, a dot `.` does NOT include newlines, only when you use the `s` modifier.
[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression should match any character except newlines

```
/[^\n]+/
```

Comment: yes, except the original matches the empty string and this one requires at least one non-linebreak character... "/[^\n]*/"

(and if you're on Windows, you might want to exclude \r as well...)

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior shouldn't match a new line. Because the "s" modifier is used to make the dot match all characters, including new lines. Maybe you can provide an example to look at?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$test = "Some\ntest\nstring";

// Echos just "Some"
preg_match('/(.*)/', $test, $m);
echo "First test: ".$m[0]."\n";

// Echos the whole string.
preg_match('/(.*)/s', $test, $m);
echo "Second test: ".$m[0]."\n";
```

So I don't know what is wrong with your program, but it's not the regex (unless you have the `/s` modifier in your actual application.

Answer (score 0):

this is strange, because by default the dot (.) does not accept newlines. Most probably you have a "\r" (carriage return) character there, so you need to eliminate both: `/[^\r\n]/`

ah, you were using /s